# Rubocop - how to disable warnings for missing else-clause?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

How do I silence Rubocop warnings for a case-statement that does not include an else-clause? I tried the following value in my .rubocop.yml file without any success:

```
Style/MissingElse:
  Enabled: false
```

My case-statement looks like this:

```
case value
when 4..9 then x
when 10..15 then y
when 16..22 then z
end
```

Since the value tested cannot fall outside the range 4 - 22, I see little point in adding an else-clause.

Comment: If it __can't__ fall outside of that range, then make the last `when` an `else`?

Comment: how can you be sure it won't fall outside the range?

Comment: I'd suggest what @SergioTulentsev said as well. If it is possible for the _value_ to fall outside the range `raise` an error in the `else` statement

Comment: That would be a solution, but it would be less evdident that the maximum value is 22 when looking at just the case-statement.

Comment: I will settle with an else-statement for the final case as this satisfies Rubocop while also being a good-enough code solution in my opinion.

Comment: If it should never be outside of the range, raise a runtime error in the else. It may catch a future bug, and it helps to self-document the intended behaviour.

Comment: This cop is disabled by default, so your disable won't change anything unless there's another configuration file. In order to assess the question, you'll need to post the output from `rubocop` and your version.

Answer (score 6):

Don’t disable it globally, suppress it inplace:

```
# rubocop:disable Style/MissingElse
case value
when 4..9 then x
when 10..15 then y
when 16..22 then z
end
# rubocop:enable Style/MissingElse
```

Comment: I get an "unnecessary disabling of Style/MissingElse" warning, which means that my global configuration should do the trick. However, when I remove the global configuration, having suppressed it in place, I get the same warning.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You might need to check `.rubocop_todo.yml` as well, but in general either this cop is disabled and you don’t need to do anything, or it’s enabled and the solution above should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my statement. What I meant to say was that your solution for in place suppression seems to behave exactly like my global suppression, which means that both are ineffective.

Comment: This is how you do it. If it's not working that would be... interesting.

Comment: It is interesting indeed. My other suppressions work just fine.